# Smart IDE for Code Obfuscation

Tags: javascript, ide

I'm writing some obfuscated code, but as the script is progressing it's getting more and more difficult to track variables. For example I have at the top of the script:

```
aP = "getElementsByTagName";
```

But further on in the script aP might become something else. When you're dealing with a lot of variables it gets tedious for the mind to track what's actually going on.

Are there any IDE's that are able to map where each variable is pointing to? Or to build a sort of tree like view similar to how IDA does when reverse engineering?

I'm using JavaScript for this by the way and working on a Mac. I already own BBEdit so I'm not sure if theres any helpful plugins for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just write your Javascript using proper naming and good indentation.

You can always obfuscate it when deploying, using one of the many tools available.

See this SO question and answers: [How can I obfuscate JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript).

Comment: I already know how to obfuscate after a script has been written. But obfuscating manually isn't really a problem the only issue I have is keeping track of the variables. I've been doing it for a while this way but was just wondering if there was a solution for keeping track of them. Increased memory. Increased problem solving performance. It has it's pluses :D

Comment: @GV1 - Writing your code obfuscated to begin with just look like unnecessary complication.